# Can not send mail from html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, contact-form

I have been working on a single page website. It have like 8 pages. Last one is contact form. I have a PHP function "send_mail.php" that posts the data to my gmail account. This code is only working if i put it in a separate html but if i call this function through my index.html, it doesnt send the email.

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8">
                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <h3>Contact Info</h3>
                        <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="mail/send_mail.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#bottom-->
```

and then my php

```
    <?php function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }}$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ; 
$name = $_REQUEST['user_name'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['email_subject'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: index.html" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: index.html" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: index.html" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email!
else {
mail( "abcd@gmail.com", $subject,
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: index.html" );
}
?>
```

Somehow I found the error location but couldnt narrow it down. If I remove my js references, i can send email though.

Comment: PHP isn't processed in a .html file. The file name needs to end in .php (unless you've configured your server differently).

Comment: I started to customize Multi theme (Free HTML theme available on internet). But the send_mail function was copied by somewhere else as the theme SENDMAIL.php was not working. No change has been made in js, just the frontend was edited.

Comment: yes, my php function is saved in SEND_MAIL.PHP in same directory.

Comment: I can share the link to my js files if you want.
I have two html file (index.html, contact.html), one php (send_mail.php)
same code for contact form in both htmls. Just the difference is contact.html doesnt call any js file. ANd it works. It send email, but not the index.html that calls java files.